# Where do the "spare" balls come from in Test Match cricket?

Tags: cricket

If a ball has gone out of shape and needs to be changed, the umpires bring out a box of balls which are similar to one being bowled. Where do these other balls come from?

Answer (score 3):

They are balls used in previous matches and kept to be used as spares.   They will be the same type of ball as being used.

The umpires then look for a ball of similar wear and tear.